# jaxws:endpoint inInterceptors not called correctly

Tags: jax-ws

Handle Message for interceptor getting called after the service method is called

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="service" implementor="#testServiceimpl"
        address="/testService"> 
     <jaxws:inInterceptors>
            <bean id="test"
        class="org.example.Test"/>
     </jaxws:inInterceptors>
     </jaxws:endpoint>

public class TestInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public TestInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.INVOKE);
    }

@Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        System.out.println("Test");
}
}
```

Comment: Code? What phase did you wire the interceptor to?

Comment: Hi Kolossus, i am wiring the interceptor at Invoke phase:Phase.INVOKE...Same interceptor if i use in cxf:bus is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

super(Phase.PRE_INVOKE);

For this issue interceptor should be executed in PRE_INVOKE phase